# HQL MEMBER OF to criteria conversion

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, member

I have some trouble porting my HQL query to criteria.

For the abstraction let's say I have entities Transaction, Account, Group and History such as Transaction -> Group -> Account <- History <- Transaction. Please also see ER diagram below:

[image]

I use the next HQL query for getting all transactions either with null-group or with account in the group:

```
FROM Transaction t
INNER JOIN t.history AS h
INNER JOIN t.group AS g
WHERE t.group IS NULL OR history.account MEMBER OF g.accounts
```

And now I need to convert my query to `DetachedCriteria`, but don't know how as hibernate restrictions don't have methods for `MEMBER OF` criteria.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I hope, the working query is:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Transaction.class, "t")
.createAlias("t.history", "h")
.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("t.group"),
     Subqueries.propertyNotIn("h.account.id", DetachedCriteria.forClass(Group.class, "g")
    .createAlias("g.accounts", "a", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.eqProperty("t.group.id", "g.id"))
    .add(Restrictions.isNotNull("a.id"))
    .setProjection(Projections.property("a.id")))));
```

It solves our problem. I mark this answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Restrictions.eqProperty as following. Hope this will help you.

```
DetachedCriteria hsql = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Transaction.class, "t")
   .addAlias("t.history", "h")
   .addAlias("t.group", "g")
   .add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.isNull("t.group"),
        Restrictions.eqProperty("h.account", "g.account")
   ));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work for me because group contains collection of accounts, so I can't compare single value with a collection :(

Comment: Restrictions.in("h.account", new String[] {/* accounts */}), get the collection of account names and use Restrictions.in

Comment: I already thought about this approach, but it's heavyweight and not scalable as I can have thousands of transactions and hundreds of groups and accounts. Thus I will be forced to load from DB all the accounts related to the group for each transaction instead of doing the same via the query without need to load a lot of data.

Comment: Sorry, man, your answer was near right. It seems to work fine with eqProperty, but I simplified question and originally I needed `NOT MEMBER OF`. It seems, that Hibernate won't work just with `neProperty` as it finds another accounts in collection that are not equal to the specified and returns true.